# File type not allowed - pdf upload - HippoCMS

Tags: hippocms

While uploading .pdf files bigger than 1MB in size through assets in Hippo CMS it gives an error "File type not allowed".

I have already checked  MySQL configuration and checked /hippo:configuration/hippo:frontend/cms/cms-services/assetValidationService node in hippo console, where default value is 10M.

So the specific question is:
How do you fix the error and are able to upload files bigger than 1MB in Hippo CMS of .pdf type.

Answer (score 1):

checkout:

http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/editor-interface/image-and-asset-upload-validation.html

Here you can see how to set the file size limit. Note that there is also possibly a wicket setting you have to be aware of. Details in the page.

Though I wouldn't expect it to return file type not allowed if the problems was the size of the file. Perhaps the file is not validating as a pdf?

Comment: Also see if there are any exceptions logged. Turn level to DEBUG it gives more information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually on the server of nginx. The server was rejecting all files bigger then 1MB and after long check at the logs the setting got changed to appropriate size.
I also gave the vote to Jasper since that can also be solution and it effects the same problem.